# One to many SQL design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm new in MySQL and looking to make a table of chairs.

Each chair can be in several categories, but I realize SQL is a single data column structure.

How would it be possible to design a "chair" table?

Also, how would a query for fetching chair_id by category look like?

There are 18 diffrenet categories.

For example,

`chair_id = 1 , categories = 'living room', 'kitchen', 'garden'`
`chair_id = 2 , categories = 'kitchen', 'garden'`
`chair_id = 3 , categories = 'garden'`

```
Fetch where category='kitchen' || 'living room' => chair_id = 1,2
```

Comment: Doen't take long to get search results try this one https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9401/database-schema-for-a-product-with-multiple-categories-and-hierarchical-categori

Comment: At this point, an hour or so in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be highly beneficial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is a **relational** database system. You should model your data as relations:

- there are chairs
- there are categories
- every chair can belong to any number of categories
- every category can contain any number of chairs

This directly leads to **three tables**:

- `chairs`
- `categories`
- `chairs_in_categories`

The third table has only two columns, the first referencing the ID of a chair, the second referencing the ID of a category. An entry in this table indicates that a chair belongs to a category.

Comment: thank you. Does the Chair_ID in 'chairs_in_categories' is a foreign key of 'chairs'?

Comment: Yes, the `chair_id` is a FK that references `chair(id)`.

Comment: Tips on indexing a many:many table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table